# Why does correlation come out the same on raw data and z-scored (standardized) data?

Tags: correlation, standardization

I just discovered by mistake that raw data and the same z scored data produces the same correlation. Why is this? Can someone walk me through the logic?

```
> x = c(2,4,6,7,8,3,6,8,9)
> y = c(3,3,5,7,6,8,9,10,5)
> cor(x,y)
[1] 0.3780247
> zx = (x-mean(x))/sd(x)
> zy = (y-mean(y))/sd(y)
> cor(zx,zy)
[1] 0.3780247
```

Comment: To me, this is by *definition*: correlation is one of those properties of pairs of datasets that does not change when either (or both) are shifted or rescaled.  Among all such properties that can be expressed in terms of moments it is the simplest. (That defines it up to a nonzero multiple which can be pinned down by requiring that "perfect" correlation (of a set of data $(x_i,x_i)$) equals $1$.)  This shows that your question is incomplete: you need to give us *your* definition of correlation.

Answer (score 4):

Two facts:

(i) Correlation is the covariance of the z-scores.

(e.g. see [here](http://faculty.frostburg.edu/math/monline/stat/41_p1.html) about four-fifths of the way down the page; alternatively, try

```
zx = scale(x)  # this returns z-scores directly, but you can use your form instead
zy = scale(y)
cov(zx,zy);cor(x,y)
```

to see that covariance of z-scores and correlation are the same.

(ii) If you takes z-scores of z-scores you get z-scores. You can see this by direct reasoning (if the mean and standard deviation are already 0 and 1, you change nothing by subtracting 0 and dividing by 1), and you can double-check by looking at `scale(scale(x))`

Hence the correlation of the z-scores is the covariance of the z-scores of the z-scores, which is just the covariance of the z-scores, which is just the correlation of the original scores.

Answer (score 1):

Correlation is scale-invariant.  Try

```
> cor(zx, y)
```

and you'll see that the correlation between the raw and z scored data is also the same.